# Matching indexOf array element

Tags: javascript

I have this code in javascript

```
var array = [
  'apples',
  'eggs'
];

var search = prompt('Write one from this words ' + array.join(" "));

console.log(search);

if ( array.indexOf( search ) === search ) {
  alert("Yep");
}
```

It should display alert if user writes apples or eggs, but it does not do anything? Why?

Comment: When something doesn't work as you expect, check documentation for the methods or functions; this would have explained clearly what [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns, and hence why it "*does not do anything.*"

Comment: You might be looking for `if (array.includes(search))`

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
if ( array.indexOf( search ) >= 0) {
  alert("Yep");
}
```

as `indexOf` will return the index if the item has been found. It will return `-1` if the item is not found.

See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)